# How to avoid coercion of numeric values to NA in R

Tags: r, numeric, coercion

I have a data frame column **x** of character mode and class. The element in the column are all numeric values. I'm trying to convert the column values from character to numeric, but when I type `as.numeric(x)` only the integer values remain numeric, all the non-integer values (i.e 3.14) are coerced in NA. Why? How can I convert it to a column of numeric values avoiding the coercion to NA?
This is the output of `dput(PercentageCont)`:

```
c("50,9", "56,9", "64", "57", "61,4",......)
```

When I do as.numeric all the floating point values are coerced in NA.

Comment: as.numeric(as.character(x))?

Comment: Please add the output of dput(x) to your question.

Comment: This is the output of `dput(PercentageCont)
c("50,9", "56,9", "64", "57", "61,4",......)` . When I do as.numeric all the floating point values are coerced in NA

Comment: You decimal separator is a comma. The function `as.numeric()` wants a decimal point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the commas. Here is my solution:

```
# convert comma to dot
dot = gsub(",","\\.", c("50,9", "56,9", "64"))

[1] "50.9" "56.9" "64"

# transform string into numeric
as.numeric(dot)

[1] 50.9 56.9 64.0
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the reason